# Angular 2 Webpack angular-router-loader, Causes Null Response

Tags: angular, webpack

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOySe.png)

loaders: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
          } ,
          'angular2-template-loader',
          'angular-router-loader'
        ]

This occurs when I use angular-router-loader in webpack, however without it I cannot implment lazy loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me too and I was so stumped.
I'm not sure why this is the case but apparently angular tries to access the prototype of the arrow function the loader puts inside the loadChildren property, but es6's native arrow functions don't have a prototype whereas simple functions do.

If you change your tsconfig.json to target es5 it'll work since it'll compile these arrow functions to normal functions and then it'll work.

A different workaround would be to simulate router-loader and just place normal functions returning a promise so you could keep on using es6 compilation.

Hope it was indeed the case with you!

Comment: Thanks,I ended up just migrating everything over to angular-cli... made life easier.

Comment: Understandable, I just like to know everything from the bottom up, which is not the case by using the cli